# Comparing an element in one table with a sum of elements in another table that share the same foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database that I want to compare. One table is a bill table, and the other is something similar to bill payments, by that I mean that a single bill can have more than one payment.

How do I create a statement that checks whether the bill amount let's say is equal to however bill payments that one bill has (the id in the bill table is a foreign key in bill payments)?

Comment: Please include sample data for the two tables, along with the output you expect.

Comment: The output I expect that it shows me the tuples that don't meet the condition.

Comment: As for sample data, the bill table has 4 columns, id, bill amount, date and status. And the other table, bill payment, has 4 as well, id, bill_id(the foreign key), amount, date.

Comment: To repeat: Please include sample data for the two tables, along with the output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have table1 bill as shown below

[image: fig 1]

payments table as shown below

[image: fig 2]

use below query

```
select b.bill_no,b.bill_date,b.bill_amount,sum(p.pay_amount) as ttl_amt_paid
from table1 b
Join table2 p on b.bill_no = p.bill_no
group by b.bill_no,b.bill_date,b.bill_amount
```

If you need all the bill details from `table1` please use `left join` for `table2`

Thanks

Comment: This was very helpful thank you, however is it possible to maybe filter the results so that it only shows the tuples where the payments do not equal the bill amount? Very thankful!!

Comment: yes you can use below query select * from (select b.bill_no,b.bill_date,b.bill_amount,sum(p.pay_amount) as ttl_amt_paid
from table1 b
Join table2 p on b.bill_no = p.bill_no
group by b.bill_no,b.bill_date,b.bill_amount)k where bill_amount > ttl_amt_paid